# Access array elements using foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I'm studying php and now I'm struggling in following: i have an array that contains other array like this:

```
$leftMenu = array(
    array('link'=>'Домой', 'href'=>'index.php'),
    array('link'=>'О нас', 'href'=>'about.php'),
    array('link'=>'Контакты', 'href'=>'contact.php'),
    array('link'=>'Таблицы умножения', 'href'=>'table.php'),
    array('link'=>'Калькулятор', 'href'=>'calc.php')                
);
```

What i need to do, is draw a menu with hyperlinks by html and this array, using foreach. That is what i tried to do:

```
foreach ($leftMenu as $key=>$value){
    foreach ($value as $html=>$link){
        echo "<a href=$html>$link </a>\n"; 
    }   
}
```

Obviously it doesn't work because i get invalid values in variable $link. What i want to, is pass only links to that variable, not text. How to achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a dropdown list from a multi-dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977299/create-a-dropdown-list-from-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to loop twice in your array but once

```
foreach ($leftMenu as $value){
    echo '<a href="'.$value['href'].'">'.$value['link'].'</a>'."\n";   
}
```

[**Live working sample here**](http://codepad.org/HNOgrZz6)

Comment: Thank you Fabio. If i understand correct i can use $value like i use an array?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban: `$value` *is* an array and you *are* using it as such.  Add `print_r($value);` inside the loop to see the contents of the array on each loop iteration.

Comment: @evgeniyKleban Amal is right you can use as array because it is an array

Comment: @Fabio are you free atm?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($leftMenu as $key=>$value){
        foreach ($value as $html=>$link){
                if ($html != 'link')    {
                    echo "<a href='{$html}'>{$link}</a>\n";
                }
        }   
    }
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
foreach ($leftMenu as $a){
    $link = $a["link"];
    $href = $a["href"];
    echo "<a href=\"$href\">$link </a>\n";

}
```

demo : https://eval.in/105138